# Nginx 2 servers 1 port

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, mariadb, nextcloud

I know this can be done in Apache and I am still new to nginx but how do I based on the domain entering do I send it to a different server?

So I basically have 2 sites I just use for messing about with and I want to use nextcloud but this will have to be on a different domain

Example

Website1.com  is on 192.168.1.4
Website2.com is on 192.168.1.4

Nextcloud.website1.com is on 192.168.1.5

The main set up is on 192.168.1.4 with all the server blocks and it works well and is so fast with the SSD powering everything.

I am guessing when the request comes through for next loud.website1.com it hits 192.168.1.4 and the. The config sends that domain to 192.168.1.5 nginx server block.

I just cannot find any examples on hope to do this and I am pretty stuck.

Hope your all well

Riddle

Comment: _"have 2 sites I just use for messing about with"_     Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Using the block in the comment.